# Include resources on compilation visual studio

Tags: c#, resources

Hello, my problem is that I have images in my project, and when I compile the project it creates the images of the project on the Release folder, however I wanted them in the EXE.

Image resources config:

action of compilation: Content

copy on results directory: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set build action to embedded resource.

[image: EmbeddedResource]